# flash message in Rails stays until next webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2, flash-message

When I use rails' `redirect_to` method in a controller and pass it a `notice` message, everything works great. The notice is shown at the top for the page redirected to and then disappears when the next page is visited.

However, if I instead set a flash message and then simply render a page, then the flash message is shown, but it's ***also shown on the next page visited***:

```
flash[:alert] = 'Please fix mistakes outlined in red'
render action: 'show'
```

How do I not make the alert message show on the next page that's visited. I **only** want that alert message shown on this page being rendered.

Using Rails 3.2.8

Comment: Also asked in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613952/why-flash-message-wont-disappear) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017210/rails-flash-message-remains-for-two-page-loads).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`now` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now):

```
flash.now[:alert] = 'Please fix mistakes outlined in red'
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Exactly what I was looking for